# how can i add a score tracker to my pong game using tkinter and why am i getting a position type error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm getting the following error:
TypeError: initialisePaddle() missing 1 required positional argument: 'color'
even if i already included a color argument into the code? or should I've added a global color variable?
Also how do I add a score tracker, which gives a point each time player1/2's ball makes contact/collision with a paddle?

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
myHeight=400
myWidth=800
mySpeed=10
scoreplayer1=0
scoreplayer2=0

def initialiseBall(dx,dy,radius,color):
    b=[myWidth/2,myHeight/2,dx,dy,radius]
    b.append(myCanvas.create_oval(myWidth/2-radius,myHeight/2-radius,\
                                  myWidth/2+radius,myHeight/2+radius,\
                                  width=2,fill=color))
    return b

def initialisePaddle(x,y,width, height, radius,color):
    r=[x,y,0,0,width,height]
    r.append(myCanvas.create_rectangle(x-width/2,y-height/2,\
                                      x+width/2,y+height/2,\
                                      width=2,fill=color))
    return r

def updateBall():
    # new position calculation
    global scoreplayer1, scoreplayer2 
    newX=balle[0]+balle[2]
    newY=balle[1]+balle[3]
    hit1=paddle1[0]+paddle1[4]
    hit2=paddle2[1]+paddle2[5]
    
    if newY<0 or newY>=myHeight:
        newY=balle[1]
        balle[3]*=-1         
    # intersection with paddles

    bbox1 = myCanvas.bbox(paddle1[6])
    bbox2 = myCanvas.bbox(paddle2[6])
        
    if newX <= bbox1[2] and (newY>bbox1[1] and newY<bbox1[3]):
        newX=balle[0]
        balle[2]*=-1  
        scoreplayer1+=1    
    if newX >= bbox2[0] and (newY>bbox2[1] and newY<bbox2[3]):
        newX=balle[0]
        balle[2]*=-1
        scoreplayer2+=1      
    # update of coordinates
    balle[0]=newX
    balle[1]=newY
    # update of graphic element 
    myCanvas.coords(balle[5],\
                    balle[0]-balle[4],balle[1]-balle[4],\
                    balle[0]+balle[4],balle[1]+balle[4])    
def updatePaddle(r):
    newY=r[1]+r[3]
    if newY-r[5]/2<0 or newY+r[5]/2>=myHeight:
        newY=r[1]
        r[3]=0
    r[1]=newY
    myCanvas.coords(r[6],\
                    r[0]-r[4]/2,r[1]-r[5]/2,\
                    r[0]+r[4]/2,r[1]+r[5]/2)       
def animation():
    global score
    updateBall()
    updatePaddle(paddle1)
    updatePaddle(paddle2)
    myCanvas.after(mySpeed,animation)    

def movePaddles(event):
    if event.keysym == 'a':
        paddle1[3]=-5
    if event.keysym == 'q':
        paddle1[3]=5
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        paddle2[3]=-5
    if event.keysym == 'Down':
        paddle2[3]=5
def stopPaddles(event):
    if event.keysym == 'q' or event.keysym == 'a':
        paddle1[3]=0
    if event.keysym == 'Up' or event.keysym == 'Down':
        paddle2[3]=0
mainWindow=Tk()
mainWindow.title('Pong')
mainWindow.geometry(str(myWidth)+'x'+str(myHeight))
myCanvas=Canvas(mainWindow,bg='dark grey',height=myHeight,width=myWidth)
myCanvas.pack(side=TOP)
balle=initialiseBall(5,5,20,'red')
paddle1=initialisePaddle(60,myHeight/2,40,100,'green')
paddle2=initialisePaddle(myWidth-60,myHeight/2,40,100,'blue')
mainWindow.bind("<Key>",movePaddles)
mainWindow.bind("<KeyRelease>",stopPaddles)
animation()
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the previous answer suggested you need to remove the radius parameter.
To display the score you can use the `Label` widget. Once the ball goes out you need to stop the game so keep a global variable say `gameOver=False` and assign it `True` only if the ball goes out.

your `updateBall` function should look something like this.

```
def updateBall():
    # new position calculation
    global scoreplayer1, scoreplayer2, gameOver 
    newX=balle[0]+balle[2]
    newY=balle[1]+balle[3]
    hit1=paddle1[0]+paddle1[4]
    hit2=paddle2[1]+paddle2[5]
    
    if newY<0 or newY>=myHeight:
        newY=balle[1]
        balle[3]*=-1         
    # intersection with paddles

    bbox1 = myCanvas.bbox(paddle1[6])
    bbox2 = myCanvas.bbox(paddle2[6])
      
    if (newX < bbox1[2] and newX>bbox1[0]) and (newY>=bbox1[1] and newY <= bbox1[3]):
        newX=balle[0]
        balle[2]*=-1  
        scoreplayer1+=1

        score.config(text=f'Player1: {scoreplayer1}')
        
    if (newX > bbox2[0] and newX<bbox2[2]) and(newY>=bbox2[1] and newY<=bbox2[3]):
        newX=balle[0]
        balle[2]*=-1
        scoreplayer2 +=1

        score2.config(text=f'Player2: {scoreplayer2}')

    if newX<-20 or newX>myWidth+20:    
        gameOver = True
        
                
    # update of coordinates
    balle[0]=newX
    balle[1]=newY
    # update of graphic element 
    myCanvas.coords(balle[5],\
                    balle[0]-balle[4],balle[1]-balle[4],\
                    balle[0]+balle[4],balle[1]+balle[4])
```

and your `animation` function:

```
def animation():
    global score, gameOver
   
    if not gameOver:
        updateBall()
        updatePaddle(paddle1)
        updatePaddle(paddle2)
        
        myCanvas.after(mySpeed,animation)

    else:
        play = messagebox.askquestion('GameOver', f'GameOver!\nplayer1 score: {scoreplayer1}\nplayer2 score: {scoreplayer2}'\
                               '\n Do you want to continue? ')
        if play == 'yes':
            gameOver = False
            myCanvas.moveto(balle[5], myCanvas.winfo_reqwidth()//2, myCanvas.winfo_reqheight()//2)
            balle[0]=myCanvas.winfo_reqwidth()//2
            balle[1]=myCanvas.winfo_reqheight()//2
            myCanvas.after(100,animation)
```

the labels

```
mainWindow.geometry(f'{myWidth+100}x{myHeight+100}')
score = Label(mainWindow, text='Player1: 0')
score.pack()

score2 = Label(mainWindow, text='Player2: 0')
score2.pack()
```

Also, don't forget to import `messagebox`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove radius from

```
def initialisePaddle(x,y,width, height, radius,color):
```

to eliminate the error.